# Uncaught TypeError: showItems is not a function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I didn't know what had went wrong where i had defined the function but it still giving error.

```
var sampleData = [
  { id: 1, name: "name", items: ["foo", "bar"] }
];
var defaultColumns=[
  { field: "id" },
  { field: "name" },
  { field: "items", "template":kendo.template("#= showItems(items) #") }
];


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {data:sampleData},
  columns:defaultColumns
});
function showItems(arr) {
  return arr.join("</br>") ;
}
```

[My sample code](http://jsbin.com/rucayo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Don't link to your code just put it in the question itself.

Comment: when i put the code in code snippet. it work perfectly fine but on JS bin had the exactly same but it give me that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the solution by declaring the showItems in global and it perfectly fine.

```js
    function showItems(arr) {
      return arr.join("</br>");
    }

    var sampleData = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "name",
      items: ["foo", "bar"]
    }];
    var defaultColumns = [{
      field: "id"
    }, {
      field: "name"
    }, {
      field: "items",
      "template": kendo.template("#= showItems(items) #")
    }];


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: sampleData
      },
      columns: defaultColumns
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kendo UI Grid</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="grid"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `showItems` is defined in the **global JavaScript scope** in your actual application. This is required for custom functions called from inside Kendo UI templates:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#handle-external-templates-and-expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
 var sampleData = [
    { id: 1, name: "name", items: ["foo", "bar"] }
 ];
 var defaultColumns=[
    { field: "id" },
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "items", template: showItems }
 ];


 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {data:sampleData},
    columns:defaultColumns
 });

 function showItems(arr) {
   return arr.items.join("</br>") ;
 }
```